# HLS.js Custom license server

Tags: video.js, http-live-streaming, fairplay, hls.js

What is the best way to use HLS.js to make a custom license request to play encrypted HLS content?  What I'm looking for is to override the AES URI that's in the manifest with one of my own, a.k.a. overriding the LAURL

```
const vid = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

const config = {
  debug: true,
  startPosition: 100,
  maxBufferHole: 0.5,
  maxSeekHole: 2,
};
const hls = new Hls(config);

hls.attachMedia(vid);

hls.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, function () {
  console.log('hls and videojs are bound together');
  hls.loadSource('https://example.com/movie.m3u8');
  hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function (event, data) {
    console.log('manifest parsed, found ' + data.levels.length + ' quality levels');
  });
});
```

Should I be using HLS.js's [custom loader](https://github.com/dailymotion/hls.js/blob/master/API.md#loader)?